# How to read response content with content-type as "image/svg+xml" in DOT NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-core, svg, httpresponse, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to read the response content which is coming as svg format. But not able to find the content within the response object.
I'm expecting some svg content within it.

Here is the code snippet:

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HeaderNames.Accept, "image/svg+xml");
var resultAsAsync = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(_url, JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object>(requestBody), cancellationToken);
var response = await resultAsAsync.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ChartsDO>(); // Failing as the response is not type of JSON
```

StatusCode is coming as 200(Ok), content type "{image/svg+xml}" and has content length of 19331.

[image]

In postman, it runs fine, and if I want I can save the response object to svg directly.

[image]

I'm using .NET CORE 5.
Any help is highly appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: You are parsing the response as JSON... SVG is XML, so you need to parse the content as XML.

Comment: try `var content = await resultAsAsync.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

Comment: Refer to this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent?view=net-7.0), I don't find any method can deal with xml, You can try to use `ReadAsStringAsync()` method.

Comment: ReadAsStringAsync method worked perfectly, I tried this several times but not sure why it was not working.